# Possible to restrict access to priority field?

Tags: jira

Is it possible to restrict write access to the priority field in JIRA? We're hoping to have a small list of admins set priority levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard JIRA doesn't support field-level access in general. But the easiest approach is to use the JIRA Behaviours plugin. You can also use custom javascript in the field configuration for the Priority field to change its accessibility.